# How to show date of birth in jquery-datepicker

Tags: mysql, laravel, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to show saved date of birth from sql in jquery datepicker.
date picker is showing today date by default, but i want it to show saved date in SQL when i am clicking on edit profile. i am doing it in Laravel.

```
<input type="text" name="dob"  class="datepicker form-control" value="{{$teacher->dob}}">

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({

      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd'

    });
  } );
  </script>
```

it should show saved date of birth.

Comment: and what is the problem? you don't know how to get the date from database or how to set the date in datepicker?

Comment: it's showing today date. 28-April-2019, but it should actually show  01-Jan-1960  date of birth saved in SQL.

Comment: I personnally never had a problem with jquery datepicker, i generally output the date from the database in the same format as the datepicker inside the value attribute and it works well. Did you try to set up a hard coded date inside your date picker (just for testing purpose, something like `value="01-Jan-1960"`)? Is this format (01-Jan-1960) the exact format that shows if you manually select this date with the date picker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `defaultDate`:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
      defaultDate: '01/02/03'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i don't want default date, i want to fetch dates from SQL.

Comment: if you don't know how to fetch the date from SQL and put it instead the one in example, then you should edit your question to make it clear, I asked about that in comment, and you said that you don't know how to set it, not how to get it from database and insert into your code, and add proper tags (like `MySQL` or whatever database you are using) as well as database schema.

Comment: "please read last line of my question: "it should show saved date of birth

Comment: But you didn't even put `sql` tag in your question, so it's not clear enough. You can argue with me, or just take my advice. There are many people in here with different skill levels, not easy to tell how much you know.

Comment: You need to add some database schema as well, because it's not possible to answer your question without knowing it.